# ZWNJ not shown properly in python 3.3

Tags: python, unicode, normalization, python-3.3, unicode-normalization

I am trying to replace the space between two tokens written in the Arabic alphabet with a ZWNJ but what the function returns is not decoded properly on the screen:

```
>>> nm.normalize("رشته ها")
'رشته\u200cها'
```

\u200 should be rendered as a half-space that would be placed between 'رشته' and 'ها' here, but it gets messed up like that. I am using Python 3.3.3

Comment: ZWNJ is not a half-space but a zero-width control character that is meant to prevent ligature behavior. Any spacing caused by it is due to the design of glyphs involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returned a *string object* with the `\u200c` character as part of it, but Python shows you the *representation*. The `\uxxxx` syntax is used to make the representation useful as a debugging value, you can now copy that representation and paste it back into Python and get the exact same value.

In other words, the function *worked exactly as advertised*; the space was indeed replaced by a [U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://codepoints.net/U+200C) codepoint.

If you wanted to write the string to your terminal or console, use `print()`:

```
print(nm.normalize("رشته ها"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> result = 'رشته\u200cها'
>>> len(result)
7
>>> result[4]
'\u200c'
>>> print(result)
رشته‌ها
```

You can see that character 5 (index 4) is a single character here, not 6 separate characters.